# store negative number in char array ( still no requirred/desired solution )

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, compression, user-input

```
EDIT:
  platform unix 
  type :  ansi c
```

I have data in form ;

```
1 2 3 -1 2 -9 1 3 + 
-1 2 -3 -4 -
*
```

integer in range between -9 and 9

'+ - *' operator and shows that you should take data which lies at following  line

data is char double pointer

each line must be stored in double pointer char array

```
example :   data[0] :=>  1 2 3 -1 2 -9 1 3 + 
            more precisely :  data[0][3] must store -1
```

when I take data and store, I could not achieve store -3 ( negative integer ) in data[i][j]
because '-' is a character so 3 is not accepted by data[i][j]

What should I do to handle this problem?

EDIT: MY code ;

```
size_t datalen = sizeof( char ) ;

data = ( char ** ) malloc( sizeof (char * ) ) 
for ( i = 0 ;   ; ++i ) 
   data[i] = (char * ) malloc ( datalen )
   for ( j = 0 ;  ; ++ j )
         signed char ch;
         if j !=  0 
            datalen += 1
            data[i] = ( char * ) realloc ( begin[i], datalen )
         scanf ("%c ", &ch ) 
         begin[i][j] = ch 
         if ch == OP ( op = + , - , * , / )
             break
   if strlen ( begin[i] ) == 1 
           break
```

EDIT :
     if you look at ascii table you will be understand why I am not using scanf("%d",&ch)
     http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Post some code? Note that the *signess* of `char` is implementation defined.

Comment: What is your error? Make sure you are using signed chars.

Comment: With C99 you can use "%hhd" to read a value in the range SCHAR_MIN to SCHAR_MAX directly. Otherwise scanf to an int and copy to the char. As ughoavgfhw reccommends make sure you are using `signed char`, not plain char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key here is to take advantage of the limited range of your input values.  Since your input numbers will only be single-digit integers, find several impossible input values and reserve them for operators.  For example, you can let 64 be '+', 65 can be '-', etc.  Use `strtol()` to read in the numbers one at a time, then validate them and make sure they fall in your specified range and cast them down to a char.  If you see an operator without a number attached to it, convert it to the appropriate reserved value (make 'encode_operator' and 'decode_operator' functions for cleaner code) and store it.

The downside to this method is that you cannot blindly use the stored value as a number.  When you extract the data from the array, you will have to check each value to see if it is an operator or a number.  In your case, a simple `#IS_OPERATOR(x) ((x < -9) || (x > 9))` macro should be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that integers range between -9 and 9, and want to store them in a char individually, there is a trick, though more number calculation included.

Map {-9, -8, ... , 8, 9} to {0, 1, ..., 17, 18}, by minusing -9 for every number.  At this time, you have all non-negative integers, so do what you want.  At runtime, you should convert the data stoed to its original value by adding -9.

Answer (score 0):

```
char '2' != int 2
```

why don't use use

```
int tmp; 
scanf("%d", &tmp);
data[i][j] = tmp;
```

instead? By using

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

you read just one ASCII character, that could be space, minus sign or digit.

EDIT: after consulting [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the `/` character with code 0x2F would translate to `-1` **iff** it's read in this way:

```
char c; 
scanf("%c", &c);
data[i][j] = c - '0'; // 0x2F - 0x30 == -1
```

Comment: if using scanf( "%d", ch ) ,  / will be equal to -1 in data[i][j] or vice versa due to ascii

Comment: But when I tried to use these digit and operator then I will meet the new problem, whether '/' is -1 or not

Comment: You **cannot** store the numbers and the operator-symbols in the same array, if you want to store the numbers as numbers. That is because an array stores several things of the same type, and numbers are not the same type of thing as operator-symbols. You could store them all as instances of some kind of union-type, like chanchal1987 shows. But it is probably not what you really want to do. What are you **really** trying to do? Why do you think you want to store these values in an array? What are you going to do with the array values next?

Comment: @Karl: that's why I "dropped" support for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Union array instead.

```
typedef union
{
  int num;
  char op;
} ABC;
```

Then make array of ABC.

Comment: I don't understand why this was -1'd. But you should include some kind of data to indicate which field of the union is being used - otherwise you will have to guess, and guessing wrong leads to undefined behaviour very quickly. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union .

Comment: OK. You can use an extra field for that.